# Formatting resolution details in a resolved ticket in JIRA

Tags: jira

When you are resolving a ticket in JIRA, you can add a comment with the text formatted.

I cannot find if I can do the same in the resolution details field. It seems that you can place only raw text.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are referring *resolution details*, to the Resolution field in Jira, this field is a system field which only takes Text value.

The comment field in Jira is allowed to be set with Wiki Style Renderer (which enables you to configure the formatting of the content). Other renderable fields are listed [here](https://confluence.atlassian.com/adminjiraserver/configuring-renderers-938847270.html).